# Java Matcher Class

Tags: java

I need a pattern matcher to get the page id value in the below text which is coming from a http response body.

```
<meta name="ajs-page-id" content="262250">
```

What i'm after is to get the content value from this line that will always be generated in responsebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<meta\\sname=\"ajs-page-id\"\\scontent=\"(\\d+)\">");
```

That is obviously a very literal pattern... but group(1) should return the number as a string.
Haven't tested.

Comment: i'll give it a shot, can i add the body response as such: match = pattern.matcher(bodyResponse) or do i need to break it into lines?

Comment: probably should use `\\s+`  also there's no guarantee that the attributes are presented in that order, altho most likely so.

Comment: @user979587 you should be able to run it on the entire body of text. repeated calls to matcher.find() will sequentially run through every occurrence.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy a worthy point. like i said though, its a very literal pattern. plus i dont know anything about html ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse and search for the part.  You should not be using regular expressions for this.

e.g.,

```
String htmlStr = "<meta name=\"ajs-page-id\" content=\"262250\">";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr);
Element meta = doc.select("meta[name=ajs-page-id]").first();
if (meta != null)
{
    System.out.println(meta.attr("content"));
}
```

Comment: That is almost definitely safer, but depending on what else you plan on doing with the input text, a regex would almost definitely be faster and create less objects in memory. Also potentially not that much more unsafe if you know the domain of your input text very well. Its a trade off, as is everything in software development. Usually its fine to sacrifice some memory and speed for safety, but its not for everyone (i.e. the company I work at is enormously concerned with performance).

Comment: Well there's something you might have missed from the asker because he claimed that it is no longer working in a (now deleted) "answer."  I bet the tag does not stay in that pattern which is why it doesn't work and why it would have to be parsed.  I agree, if _I_ know that it would never change, I might revert to using regular expressions, but as it doesn't seem to be the case, this would be the best option.